# How to convert the Scala case class definition to Haskell?

Tags: scala, haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

I'm learning Haskell along with Scala. I tried to do define the following Scala type in Haskell, but failed:

```
sealed trait Expr
case class Value(n: Int) extends Expr
case class Add(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
case class Subtract(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
```

Could someone give me an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In scala, union types are emulated with a sealed class/trait with a number of subclasses containing the individual cases. These can be defined in Haskell directly:

```
data Expr = Value Int | Add Expr Expr | Subtract Expr Expr
```

this differs from scala in that `Value`, `Add` and `Subtract` are constructors for the `Expr` type, whereas in `Scala` the individual case classes also have their own type which can be referenced directly e.g.

```
def printValue(v: Value): Unit = { println(v.n) }
```

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to what others posted, here's a solution which uses a syntax closer to scala, relying on the small extension `GADTSyntax`.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTSyntax #-}

--- sealed trait Expr
data Expr where
   -- case class Value(n: Int) extends Expr
   Value :: Int -> Expr
   -- case class Add(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
   Add :: Expr -> Expr -> Expr
   -- case class Subtract(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
   Subtract :: Expr -> Expr -> Expr
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data Expr = Value Int | Add Expr Expr | Subtract Expr Expr
```

https://wiki.haskell.org/Algebraic_data_type